# Gulp Command not being found

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I have attempted to install Gulp using NPM but the gulp command is not getting recognized.  These are the commands I ran.  I am using Git Bash and running it as admin.  I am using Windows 10.

```
npm install gulp-cli --global
```

( Attempt to run 'gulp' and 'gulp -v' and nothing works )

Then navigating to my project folder

```
npm install gulp --save-dev
```

( Attempt Gulp command again and it still not recognized )

My `env` path for npm is `C:\Users\ *username* \AppData\Roaming\npm`

When I run

```
npm config get prefix
```

It returns `C:\Program Files\Git\Roaming\npm`

I am fairly new to NPM but I have been searching for hours and trying everything.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled Node and npm multiple times.  Sorry if this has been answered before but every other thread I found did not solve this issue.

Comment: Did you check those folders ?

Comment: You also need to install gulp globally (as well as locally, which you did).

Comment: There 2 gulp files in C:\Program Files\Git\Roaming\npm\

There are also 2 gulp folders in C:\Program Files\Git\Roaming\npm\node_modules

I am still getting the message the command not found message

Answer (score 2):

Install `gulp` and `gulp-cli` globally

```
npm install --global gulp-cli    
npm install --global gulp   
npm install gulp -D
```

**Update:**

Make sure install gulp `locally` and `globally`. After that check status using these command :

```
npm ls
npm ls -g
```

After that make sure to link gulp

```
npm link gulp
```

And maybe you should check you env.

1. Create an environmental variable called `NODE_PATH`
2. Set it to: `%AppData%\npm` ( It's you npm path )
3. Close CMD, and Re-Open to get the new ENV variables

Comment: I added that variable under my user variables.  I restarted my CMD and it is still installing new global packages into C:\Program Files\Git\Roaming\npm\

Comment: npm ls gave me C:\Program Files\Git  --empty    npm ls -g game me C:\Program Files\Git\Roaming\npm     npm link gulp returned an error for the path C:\Program Files\Git\node_modules

Comment: Did you check `npm ls` and `npm ls -g` ? @SteveGreco

Comment: yes.  Those commands both returned C:\Program Files\Git and C:\Program Files\Git\node_modules respectively.

Comment: we don't need path. find gulp in output list @SteveGreco

Comment: That is what I said before.  npm ls returns C:\Program Files\Git  --emtpy     and npm ls -g returns C:\Program Files\Git\node_modules with a list of modules and gulp and gulp-cli are in it.  The point I was trying to make was that shouldnt npm ls return the AppData/npm folder with the list of modules? @arash

Comment: You global npm in good. you have problem with local one. you should run `npm ls` in your main directory of project ( where you have `node_module` ) @SteveGreco

Comment: But the global NPM is installing packages into the GIT folder..and then I have to manually go and move all the files into AppData/npm for the commands to work.  That doesnt seem right to me.  Shouldnt the be installing where I have my path variable set?

Comment: Install location is not important, you can set ENV PATH to your `git` folder ( where global npm put packages ) @SteveGreco

Comment: I understand I can set the path to the Git folder, but I am curious why if I set my path to AppData/NPM that it is not installing them there.  That still seems like something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Add gulp to scripts in your package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
"gulp":"gulp"
},
```

Then you can use the command:

> npm run gulp name of task

Writing function like this worked for me:

```
gulp.task('message', async ( ) => { 

 console.log('gulp task is working ')
})
```

Comment: Nice. No need to install `gulp` or `gulp-cli` globally.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`npm config delete prefix`